# java constructor to assign the entire class not just fields

Tags: java

my system is both jibx and a legacy xml app and i want to build a constructor that can take a string of xml and unmarshal it into its own class.  like this:

```
public ActiveBankTO(String xmlIn)
    {
        try
        {
            ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlIn.getBytes());
            IBindingFactory bfact;
            bfact = BindingDirectory.getFactory(ActiveBankTO.class);
            IUnmarshallingContext uctx = bfact.createUnmarshallingContext();
            this = (ActiveBankTO) uctx.unmarshalDocument(bin, null);
        } catch (JiBXException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

but obviously i cant assign "this" as a variable.  is there a way to make this work?  i realize i can put this into a static method that can be used, or a few other tricks to make it work, but this is something that has come up on several projects in various forms and i was wondering if this particular method is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible.  The static method solution is the best idea.

```
public static ActiveBankTO parseActiveBankTO(String xmlIn) {
    ActiveBankTO newTO = null;
    try {
        ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlIn.getBytes());
        IBindingFactory bfact;
        bfact = BindingDirectory.getFactory(ActiveBankTO.class);
        IUnmarshallingContext uctx = bfact.createUnmarshallingContext();
        newTO = (ActiveBankTO) uctx.unmarshalDocument(bin, null);
    } catch (JiBXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return newTO;
}
```

Comment: yea, this is exactly the way i ended up going with.  just figured i would ask.

Answer (score 1):

No. ti's not possible in the constructor. A static factory method is the only real way (you can't even cheat like this in bytecode).