# C# how to make constructor for class

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core

I have a class `Response` with generic parameter:

```
public class Response<T> where T : class {
  public bool Result;
  public T Data;
}
```

Also, I have a class `Instance` with simple parameters

```
public sealed class Instance {
  public long Rank { get; set; }
  public int ID_Member { get; set; }
}
```

And then I have a class where I use last ones

```
public sealed class InstanceResponse : Response<IList<Instance>> { }
```

And I try to add a constructor to last class and don't understand how to do it

I've tried like there, but it's doesn't work, JsonString contains serialized class InstanceResponse

```
public sealed class InstanceResponse : Response<IList<Instance>> {
  public InstanceResponse(string JsonString) {
    this = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InstanceResponse>(JsonString);
  }
}
```

I've got an error `Cannot assign to 'this' because it is read-only`

How it possible?

Comment: Please define “doesn’t work.” Is it compilation errors? Runtime errors? What errors, if any? Doesn’t do what you would like?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I've got an error `Cannot assign to 'this' because it is read-only`

Comment: Yes, `this` is always read only since it’s the current object. What is your intent here? Do you mean `Data = ...` or something similar?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Full class with `Data` and `Result`

Comment: That does not explain a lot. Could you please provide an [mcve] or at least what the JSON contains or something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3687786/2133965

Comment: Json contains serialized class `InstanceResponse`

Comment: read post at link I posted above

Comment: @VietDD Use java constructor in С#?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to deserialize json to the object and assign it directly in ctor to the object itself using `this` keyword.

Provided that

> Json contains serialized class InstanceResponse

You can do something like this:

```
public sealed class InstanceResponse : Response<IList<Instance>> {
  public InstanceResponse(string JsonString) {
    var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InstanceResponse>(JsonString);
    this.Data = response.Data;
    this.Result = response.Result;
  }
}
```

Another possible solution is to deserialize json in a code that creates instance of `InstanceResponse` (call's ctor) somewhere.

Instead of:

```
var response = new InstanceResponse(json);
```

You could deserialize json right there:

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InstanceResponse>(json);
```

P.S.

With that being said, an interesting point was raised by @Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen regarding the subject. It is actually possible to assign something to `this` however it is only working inside of a `struct`s ctor and use cases for it are very limited...(thanks Lasse)

Comment: Just some unnecessary information: You are allowed to assign to `this` in the constructor of structs. Not a very useful piece of information though. This is usually done in "copy constructors". Only useful thing I can think of, in addition to knowing what it is if you see it.