# Retrieve Object from Database in Constructur

Tags: java, database, constructor, casting

I am creating a database application and want to retrieve an object from the database in its constructor.

Simplified, I want to do this:

Car car1 = new Car(1);

Whereas this piece of code should return the Car with obj ID 1.

Accordingly, the Constructor is supposed to look something like this:

```java
public class Car implements {
  Public Car() {
}

Public Car(int objId) {
  this = (Car) DB.getById(Objid); // <-- this is what does not work

}
```

What I do not want is to assign every attribute by itself and I also do not want to call

```java
Car car1 = (Car) DB.getById(1)
```

since the use case for this gets more complicated elsewhere.

Is this at all possible in Java with a reasonable implementation effort?

Comment: In your client class, you could use `Car car1 = new Car().getById(1)` and in `Car` class implement a get method.

Comment: Can't be done. Please see _Stack Overflow_ question entitled [java constructor to assign the entire class not just fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687786/java-constructor-to-assign-the-entire-class-not-just-fields)